# Abilities to limit antenna use?

Tags: antenna, united-states, legal

What kinds of abilities does a Home Owners' Association (HOA) in the United States have to limit the use of antennas placed on a roof to an owner of a home in the area?

Answer (score 8):

The only power that an HOA holds is that which is specified in the contract signed by the homeowner. This may limit towers or visible antennas. Hams have found quite a few ways around this:

- It is possible to run a large dipole inside your roof rather than outside, supporting it from the main roof beam. You could use an off-center fed or loaded dipole to get multi-band coverage.
- It is possible to run a horizontal antenna concealed under the eaves of your house
- It is possible to use a new or existing vertical metal object such as a flagpole as an antenna
- It is possible to conceal many types of antenna in a tree or yard
- It is possible and even ideal to conceal radial wires (used to improve the ground plane) underground
- Some hams have had success challenging these HOA rules in court on the grounds that they interfere with emergency communications

Comment: I was also impressed by some hams' use of metal gutters. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I share the same pain, I bought into a Home with HOA BEFORE I got interested in HAM.

A good reference for ideas for HOA restricted Antennas can be found in the ARRL's book "Small Antennas for Small Spaces".   It's chalk full of ideas.
(ARRL:  https://www.arrl.org/shop/Small-Antennas-for-Small-Spaces-2nd-Edition/)

Check YouTube, there are lots of creative ideas that appear to work.
I myself have purchased a speaker stand and mounted a J-Pole on it and put it out at night or when I need to get on the air.   Seems to work for me pretty well with my HT.  Now to get my IC-7100 up and running. :)

I saw one where a Ham put an Antenna in a flower pot and decorated it with fake/plastic flower vines.

Good look.

- A fellow like minded Ham